# Retrieve Data from Windows Registry

Tags: c#, foreach, registry

I store serialized data in the registry. I want to use a `foreach` loop to iterate through that data. On each iteration I would like to add that data to a dictionary. As follows:

1. // Create dictionary

   ```
   myDictionary = new Dictionary();
   ```
2. // iterate through previously stored data and add it to Dictionary

   ```
   foreach (object x in Application.UserAppDataRegistry.___________)
   {
    myDictionary.add(x); 
   }
   ```

Question: Is there a simple method that retrieves all data in the registry?

Comment: You've already got some answers on this, but may I ask what it is you're storing there? Generally you should be storing on minimal amounts of data and retrieving them by specific keys. If you've got a bit object graph or collection you are serializing then the registry is probably the wrong place for this information to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'm figured it out. I'm storing a bit object graph - per client specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All (you wanted to know) about the Registry with C#, Part 1 of 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4808/All-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-Registry-with-C-P) I have waiting for 6 years but there is no part 2

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Windows/Registry.htm) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctb3kd86%28VS.71%29.aspx).